# How can I use StreamBuilder using a list's length as a stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm fairly new in flutter development.

I'm making an app i which the user scans a barcode and searches the firestore database for a document with the scanned code, putting the data found on a list of maps. I've got that figured out.

However, now I need to display the data on a list, for that, I used StreamBuilder. Now, I want it to rebuild the widget whenever the length of the list changes. However I really can't seem to figure out how to actually do it since the "stream" field won't accept the list length as the stream and I can't figure out how to stream the actual length of the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, though please try to make it easy to understand since I'm still pretty new to flutter.

Update 1: I probably should have done this from the beginning but anyways here's the code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String barcode = "";
  var barcodeResult;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> productList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Barcode Scanner Example'),
          ),
          body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder(
                  initialData: productList.length,
                    stream: ,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (productList.isEmpty) {
                        return Text("You have no packages to deliver");
                      } else {
                        return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Column(children: <Widget>[
                            Text(productList[index]["field 1"]),
                            Text(productList[index]["field 2"])
                          ]);
                        });
                      }
                    }),
                new Container(
                  child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: scan, child: new Text("Scan")),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  Future scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      try {
        barcodeResult = firestore.collection("packages").document(barcode);
        productList.add(
            {"field 1": barcodeResult["field 1"], "field 2": barcodeResult["field 2"]});
      } catch (e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Object not found in database");
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() => this.barcode =
          'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to query data with StreamBuilder**

The best way would be to use the `Streambuilder` listen to the Firebase stream directly. It is both easier to implement and real time.

The steam would them look something like this

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Fruit')
    .where("code", isEqualTo: scannedBarCode).snapshots(),
```

It will rebuild anytime a document in the specified collection is updated with the scanned code.

I hope I understood your requirements and you can develop your app further!

**Edit to fix OP's problem**

After seeing the code, there is no need at all for a `StreamBuilder`, as you are not using a `Stream`, you are just querying the database and adding that information to a `List`

So the solution would be to remove the `StreamBuilder` and replace it by the code that was inside the builder with very little modifications:

```
if (productList.isEmpty)
    Text("You have no packages to deliver"),
if (productList.isNotEmpty)
    ListView.builder(
        itemCount: productList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               Text(productList[index]["field 1"]),
               Text(productList[index]["field 2"])
            ],
          );
        },
     ),
```

And not forget to initialize the `productList` to avoid null exceptions (you cannot add data to a `List` that is null,

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> productList = [];
```

I hope now it works!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've been thinking of using your solution, though I'm not sure I can since I'm working with a plugin for the scanner which works as an async function and gets the data while adding it to the list that will be displayed later. Maybe I could paste the code to give a better perspective on how everything is going? (If it's not too much trouble of course)

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems I still have a lot to learn about the widgets I'll be using, just had to do a set state so it rebuilds when something is added to the list, you are a life saver man, I appreciate it really!